# jquery ui autocomplete and php json string

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using php to fetch the data from mysql database and then use that data on the jquery ui autocomplete. But it seems like the JSON that is returned doesn't match what jquery ui needs.
The JSON returned looks something like this:

```
["dyes miran famint","annie ferrer mendrez","annie ferrer mendrez","anton setra masgre","anton setra masgre","jeniffer hades cruz","jeniffer hades cruz","alvin louie urbano maranon","alvin louie urbano maranon","francisza jerrielleza bullonza","blaze br tags anchor"]
```

I even used jQuery.parseJSON on it.

And here's what I did on the php file:

```
$class_code = $_POST['class_code'];

$student_list = array();
$students = mysql_query("SELECT accounts.id, fname, mname, lname, classcode
                        FROM account_details
                        LEFT JOIN accounts ON account_details.id = accounts.id
                        LEFT JOIN class_rooster ON accounts.id = class_rooster.id
                        WHERE accounts.status = 1 AND accounts.type='student'
                        AND (class_rooster.id  IS NULL OR classcode !='$class_code')");
$students_num = mysql_num_rows($students);
if($students_num > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($students)){

        $student_list[] = $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['mname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'];

    }
    echo json_encode($student_list);
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function get_students(){
        var class_code = $('#current_classes').val();
        $.post('student_list.php', {'class_code' : class_code},
            function(data){

                return data;
            }
        );
    }


    $("#student_name").live('click', function(){

        $("#student_name").autocomplete({
            source:  get_students()
        });
    });
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think it expects an array of objects with id and value properties, not just an array with strings.

Comment: @pinkypower - An array of strings will work according to the docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

The PHP and generated JSON look fine, the problem is likely somewhere in your Javascript. Could you post that?

Comment: yep, you're right, just checked it myself :)

Comment: please see my edit for the JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Overview section of the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) on how to use the callback source type. The second argument passed to the function is the response callback to be used. Your `get_students()` function should look something like this:

```
function get_students(current_val,callback){
        var class_code = $('#current_classes').val();
        $.post('student_list.php', {'class_code' : class_code},
            function(data){
               callback(data);
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), it's looking for something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

My guess is that you are doing `$().autocomplete(json_obj)` instead of `$().autocomplete({source: json_obj})`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the source entity in the autcompelete plugin code. Check your auto complete code

```
$("#inputbox").autocomplete({ source: data });
```

I believe You may use data without source entity

Also check your php output array